# How to "pin" C++/CLI pointers

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2008, garbage-collection, c++-cli

I am wrapping up a class which reading a custom binary data file and makes the data available to a .net/c# class

However a couple of lines down the code, i start getting the memory access violation error which i believe is due to the GC moving memory around, the class is managed

Here's the calling code in C# - reader is mixed code ( managed wrapper methods on old unmanaged code )

```
if ( ! reader.OpenFile(...) )
     return ;
foreach(string fieldName in fields)
{
   int colIndex = reader.GetColIndex( fieldName );
   int colType  = reader.GetColType( colIndex );      // error is raised here on 2nd iteration
}
for ( int r = 0 ; r < reader.NumFields(); r++ )
{
   foreach(string fieldName in fields)
   {
      int colIndex = reader.GetColIndex( fieldName );
      int colType  = reader.GetColType( colIndex );      // error is raised here on   2nd iteration

      switch ( colType )
      {
               case 0 : // INT
               processField( r, fieldName, reader.GetInt(r,colIndex) );
               break ;
           ....
      }
    }
}
....
```

Reader has an old unmanaged class instance reference which holds the binary data in memory 
AND It's a pointer type since a managed class *cannot* hold an unmanaged type

i've looked at interior_ptr, pin_ptr but they give an error c3160 cannot be in a managed class

Any workaround ? BTW, this is my 1st C++ program in a very long time !

UPDATE : 
updated the Q, again the above is the calling code and reader is mixed ( managed + old unmanaged code )

& yes the arguments are all valid

Comment: is the reader in C++? The above code looks more like C# with the foreach rather than for each.

Comment: What type is `reader`? Is it a managed type?  What's the value of `colType`? Is it a valid value?

Comment: Is the `foreach` a C# keyword or are you using the `boost` library?  AFAIK, C++ does not have a `foreach` keyword, which means you are not writing in C++!

Comment: @Thomas new C++/CLI has "for each(.. in ..)" http://blogs.msdn.com/b/arich/archive/2004/09/08/227139.aspx

Comment: Where ever the bug is located, it is not in this code.  Corrupting the heap with C++/CLI code is not difficult.

Comment: But it's "`for each`" (with a space that's required) in C++/CLI, not "`foreach`", right?

Comment: updated with answers to above Q

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the description of your code *"the class is managed"* it doesn't sound to me like memory being moved around. If `reader` is a managed class and the consumer is a managed class, all of their allocations are on the managed heap, and they don't call any unmanaged APIs, pinning isn't necessary.

It sounds more like your `reader` class is mixed mode C++ (managed plus unmanaged code).

Some things to lookout for in that case

- Is your C++ class allocating a buffer
  on the c runtime heap and trying to
  pass it to managed code?
- Is your C++
  class allocating a buffer on the
  managed heap and trying to pass it to
  unmanaged code (this is where you need pinning)?

and this one which nailed me just recently:

- If you have unmanaged C++ code are you null-ing all of your buffer allocations? An arbitrary array of bytes malloc-ed from the c-runtime heap is not nulled out the way a `gcnew array<Byte>(256)` would be. (Recently had a big **DOH** moment after a few minutes trying to figure out why `free` was blowing up in my face when I thought for sure the buffer should be `NULL`)